# Semantic analysis score as input to LSTM model for improving stock price prediction accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, data-science-model, sentiment-analysis

I have created a univariate LSTM model that is predicting value of Open Price based on last 5 years opening price of a particular stock. I'm getting a decent accuracy. Now, I want to do sentiment analysis of the news data of the last 5 years of that stock and combine that score with my existing LSTM model in order to improve the predicted values of LSTM model. Does anyone has an idea whether this implementation is possible and if yes how can I proceed. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Your problem will then become multivariate, where on top of the opening price for a particular day, you would also add a sentiment score for that day.

LSTM can handle multiple inputs natively, so there shouldn't be much for you to change.

Comment: Okay but Doesn't  the model consider both the inputs as number as we have one input as price format and the other input as a sentiment score format. I Know it's possible if all inputs are of same format i.e. price. But what about this case. Will the model be able to differentiate those automatically? And if yes should we also apply feature scaling on this sentiment score also apart from applying it on input price?

Comment: Your LSTM doesn't care if your input is a price, a sentiment score, or anything. It treats your inputs as a vector of floats. I would indeed apply appropriate scaling on each dimension (price & sentiment).